# Is there a pole version of marrow beans?

Tags: vegetables, beans

Any other rich-flavoured, white dry bean would do as well.  I'm in zone 5a or 5b, ample growing season.  I grew a few types of dry bush beans this year and even got a second crop off some of them.  Next year I want to do only pole beans. I would prefer an open-pollinated variety.  I have found white runner beans, but I don't think they have the flavour I'm thinking of.

Comment: where do you live,  do you require that the type is heirloom or commercial?

Answer (score 2):

No. Marrow beans, as well as most shell/dry beans, were developed for field cultivation, and bush types were (and still are) more efficient. I can think of one variety that may interest you, and that is the ['White Emergo' runner bean](http://www.seedaholic.com/bean-runner-bean-white-emergo-organic.html), Which can be used as a dry bean, with qualities described as similar to [cannellini](http://www.cannellini.com/). This pole veriety can climb up to 8-10 feet. It can be harvested green, or left to dry. If that isn't what your after, you may be out of options.